# Prove the circumscribed circle passes through a fixed point

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

In Acute triangle $ABC$, $PB, PC$ are tangent lines to its circumscribed circle. $E,F$ are on line $AB, AC$ such that $\angle EPF = 2 \angle BAC$. $P$ is within $\triangle AEF$. $A'$ is the symmetrical point of $A$ with respect to $EF$. Prove that the circumscribed circle of $A'EF$ passes through a fixed point.

The condition $\angle EPF = 2 \angle BAC$ is eye-catching. It would have been interesting if $P$ is the center of a certain circle. Also $\angle BPC = 180^{o} - 2 \angle A$. But I didn't go anywhere too interesting.

[image]

Comment: No, $A'EPF$ is not concyclic unless $A=60^\circ$: angle at $A'$ is $A$ and angle at $P$ is $2A$.

Comment: @user10354138 you are right

Comment: Hint: playing with GeoGebra, it seems that the fixed point is the vertex $L$ of the triangle $LBC$ obtained reflecting the triangle $ABC$ about the middle point of $BC$ (see [here](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/mxjqtbde)).

Answer (score 0):

This can be proved in two steps. The first step is, of course, locating the point.

And there is a very simple but powerful trick to do that: taking the limit.

Let's move $E$ to infinity, so $PE$ is parallel to $AB$. Since $\angle BPC=\pi-\angle BOC=\pi-2\angle A$, where $O$ is the circumcenter, and $\angle EPF=2\angle A$, we must have $\angle CPF=\pi-\angle BPE=\pi-\angle ABP=\pi/2-\angle ABO=\angle C$. Similarly, we find that $\angle PCF=\angle B$. That means, $\angle PFC=\angle A$.[image]
$A'$ is $A$ reflected w.r.t to the line through $F$ and parallel to $AB$. Now $E$ is at infinity, so the circumcircle of $\triangle EA'F$ is just the line $A'F$.

Since $EF$ is parallel to $AB$, $\angle AFE=\pi-\angle A$. So $\angle AFA'=2\angle A$. We have that $\angle PFA'\text{(facing }A\text{)}=3\angle A$.

Next, we want to do the same thing on the other side, and get the other line, and find where these two lines cross. That should be the point we are looking for.
[image]
Here I just named the point on the left side "$E$", although it doesn't correspond to the "$F$" on the right side. Just to make it clear. (Their corresponding $F$ and $E$ are at infinity.)

The same reasoning applies to the left side, too. So $\angle PEB=\angle A$, $\angle PBE=\angle C$, $\angle EPB=\angle B$. Now we have $\angle EPF=\angle BEP+\angle CFP+\angle BAC = 3\angle A=\angle PFA'$, $PE\parallel A'F$. ($A'$ is the same one in the previous picture.)

We do the same thing on the other side, draw a line through $E$ and parallel to $PF$. Let's name the intersection $G$. We have a parallelogram $PEGF$, well, unless $\angle A=\pi/3$, in which case they are all on the same line. But let's not worry about that and find the point in more general cases.

Noticing that $PB=PC$ and the angles, we have $\triangle PBE\cong \triangle PCF$, so $CF=PE$ and $BE=PF$. Because $PEGF$ is a parallelogram, we have $CF=GF$ and $BE=GE$. Noticing that $\angle PEG=\angle PFG$ and $\angle PEB=\angle PFC=\angle A$, we also have $\angle GEB=\angle GFC$. So the four angles $EBG$, $EGB$, $FCG$, $FGC$ must all be the same. Let's say it's $x$. So $\angle AEG=\angle AFG=\pi-2x$. But we have that $\angle EGF=\angle EPF=3\angle A$, and $\angle EAF+\angle EGF+\angle AEG+\angle AFG=2\pi$. Which leads to $x=\angle A$. $ABGC$ is a parallelogram.

So, indeed, the observation by @FabiusWiesner in the comment under the question is correct, the point is the symmetric point of $A$ w.r.t center of $BC$.

Now that we found the point by considering the limiting case, next we must prove that the same holds in general.

[image]
Let's denote $\angle BPE=\theta$. From here on, I'll simply denote $A,B,C$ for $\angle BAC,\angle ABC,\angle ACB$ respectively, so that I don't have to type \angle every time... Since $\angle EPF=2A$ and $\angle BPC=\pi-2A$, we have $\angle CPF=\pi-\theta$. The equations $\angle PBE=C, \angle GBE=A, \angle PCF=B, \angle GCF=A$ still hold. We want to prove that $\angle EGF=\pi-A$, and $\angle BGC=A$, so we want to prove that $\angle BGE=\pi-\angle CGF$. Let's denote $\angle BGE=\alpha$ and $\angle CGF=\beta$. And denote $PB=PC=h$. And $a, b, c$ for $BC,CA,AB$ respectively. Now we just need to prove $\alpha=\pi-\beta$.

Next, let's express everything in $\theta$ and $a,b,c,h$. We have $BE/\sin\theta=h/\sin(\theta+C)$ from $\triangle BPE$, also $BE/\sin\alpha=b/\sin(A+\alpha)$ from $\triangle BGE$, which gives $\sin(A+\alpha)/\sin\alpha=b\sin(\theta+C)/h\sin\theta$. Similarly, from the other side, we get $\sin(A+\beta)/\sin\beta=c\sin(\pi-\theta+B)/h\sin(\pi-\theta)$.

Since the result doesn't depend on $\theta$, we want to cancel out $\theta$. Expand both expressions, we get

$$\sin A \cot\alpha+\cos A=\frac{b}{h}(\cos C+\sin C\cot\theta)$$
$$\sin A \cot\beta+\cos A=\frac{c}{h}(\cos B+\sin B\cot(\pi-\theta))$$

Now we just need to multiply the first equation by $c\sin B$ and the second by $b\sin C$ and add them to cancel out the terms with $\theta$. The result is,

$$\sin A(c\sin B \cot\alpha + b\sin C \cot\beta)+\cos A(c\sin B+b\sin C)=\frac{bc}{h}\sin(B+C)$$

We have $h=r\tan A$ where $r$ is the radius of the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$, and $r=\frac{a}{2\sin A}$, so we have $h=\frac{a}{2\cos A}$. We also have $2r=\frac{a}{\sin A}=\frac{b}{\sin B}=\frac{c}{\sin C}$, so we can replace $a,b,c$ by $\sin A, \sin B, \sin C$ in the equation above. We also have $A+B+C=\pi$ so $\sin(B+C)=\sin A$. Putting all that into the equation, we have
$$\sin A\sin B\sin C(\cot\alpha+\cot\beta)+2\cos A\sin B\sin C=2\cos A\sin B\sin C$$
$$ \cot\alpha+\cot\beta=0$$
Since $0<\alpha+\beta<2\pi$, the only solution is
$$\alpha=\pi-\beta$$

The proof is complete.